# Need JQuery Graph plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, graph

Can anyone recommend any easy to use graph drawing plugins for jQuery?

I'm having some conditions

- Data must be taken from JSON.
- Graph must have PIE, LINE, BAR, COLUMN options.
- It must be Freeware.
- Possibly drill down support.
- Cross platform / browser compatible IE 9+.

I was not able to find any plugins that satisfy my needs.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/ seems to have been well-made

Comment: @ExplosionPills Highcharts are not free for commercial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following links which may help you in finding out what you need to suite your desire,

[28 Rich Data Visualization Tools](http://www.developria.com/2009/12/28-rich-data-visualization-too.html)

[13 Chart and Graph plotting javascript plugins](http://www.queness.com/post/10781/13-chart-and-graph-plotting-javascript-plugins)